# javax.propertyNotFoundException

Tags: exception, jsf-2, el

Car.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScope
public class Car{

   private List<Wheel> wheels;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
       wheels = new Arraylist<>();
   }

   public void setWheels(List<Wheel> wheels){
      this.wheels = wheels;
   }

   public List<Wheel> getWheels(){
      return wheels;
   }
}
```

TestPage.xhtml :

```
<h:form>
  <p:selectOneMenu value = "#{car.wheels}">
      <f:selectItems ... />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

When page is rendered javax.propertyNotFoundException on `#{car.wheels}` is shown
When i changed the name of wheels to c the page is rendered correctly
This exception happens a lot without knowing the problem
Am i missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide a name for the managed bean

```
 @ManagedBean(name="carss")
```

and access using that name

```
 <p:selectOneMenu value = "#{carss.xxxx}">
```

Comment: The real puzzle is that what OP was using should have worked, as that would be the default name for the managed bean if a name is not explicitly specified

Comment: @kolossus: OP didn't post compilable code. `@ViewScope` doesn't exist at all. So the code is possibly one and all red herring and the question is unsnaswerable. This answer of Sanath is completely unnecessary. The name attribute defaults to the class' instance name already (i.e. `@ManagedBean public class Car` gives `#{car}`). It's beyond me why this answer is marked accepted.

Comment: @BalusC ah I see it now. `@ViewScope`(d). Hahaha XD

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you mean

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{car.selectedWheel}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{car.wheels}" var="wheel" itemLabel="#{wheel.making}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

For selecting several values at once have a look at [h:selectManyListBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/index.html).